# Uninstall VMWare Fusion and VMWare Tools on boot camp partition

Tags: bootcamp, vmware, macos

I was using VMWare Fusion on a boot camp partition and installed VMWare Tools on the Windows volume.

How can I completely uninstall everything related to VMWare Fusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Uninstall the VMWare Tools in the VM using the uninstaller in Add/Remove Programs
- Use the Fusion uninstaller on the installation DMG to remove VMWare Fusion
- Follow [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017838) VMware KB article to clean up Fusion completely.

Sidenote: I can't find an official KB article for removing the tools, and those I do find all only mention Add/Remove. I am assuming it does a complete removal.

Comment: WHERE is _Add/Remove Programs_?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall VMWare Fusion: <sup>[(source)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014529)</sup>

   1. Quit VMWare Fusion, making sure that the VM is not running.
   2. Run the uninstaller that came in the original .dmg file.
   3. Launch the uninstaller.
2. Restart the machine and boot into the Windows partition.
3. Uninstall VMWare Tools normally via Add/Remove programs <sup>[(source)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014522)</sup>.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't realise you were planning to self answer.

Comment: @Diago: yours is good too. I'll accept it.